# Swagger UI for ASP.NET Core Web API freezing for ActionResult<T> return type

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swagger UI in ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 6 version) project using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI package.

When I try to execute a Post request, whose return type is `ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>`, with Swagger UI, it freezes for ever.

But when I change the return type to IActionResult it executes fine.

Am I missing anything here? What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you share your sample code ? I create test code as you mentioned, and can't reproduce the issue.